# Google Maps polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, math

I have a lat/long coordinate point and I'm drawing a polygon (hexagon) around it on a Google map. Here's my code to calculate the hexagon coordinates:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    x =  lat + r * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / 6);
    y =  lng + r * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / 6);
}
```

This calculates all coordinates in a regular hexagon and I can draw it on the map without a problem if its center is near (0 lat, 0 long). The problem is when I want to draw it far from (0, 0) this gets into an elongated shape. I'm guessing it's because the earth is not flat and Google maps takes that into account. So I probably need to change the radius in my calculation to reflect this, has anyone any idea how it is done?

Comment: How far from `(0,0)` do you have to go to get a problem? What do the actual numbers look like in that situation?

Comment: I only tried (46, 23). I haven't looked at the actual numbers I just saw the shape of the hexagon was not regular as it should have been because the coordinates are calculated correctly (based on an accepted answer here on SO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Examples](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_eshapes.html) of various regular polygons far from (0,0)

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me what does this calculate: `var d = 2 * 25000 * Math.cos(Math.PI / 6);` ?

Comment: See [the "documentation"](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/eshapes.htm) on eshapes. It is the distance between the centers of the hexagons in the hex grid.